# Fetch all string value pair from Constant.java File

Tags: java, string, if-statement, constants

I have an existing `Constant.java` using which I have to write a logic so that if input string contains any of the constant string then do something.

```
 public class Constants {

    public static final String CONSTANT_ONE = "VALUE_CONSTANT_ONE";
    public static final String CONSTANT_TWO = "VALUE_CONSTANT_TWO";
    //and so on..
}
```

`Validate.checkPhrase()` is a Boolean method that accepts input string and constants strings as argument, converts them to lower case and passes output to `java.lang.String.contains()` method to validate.

In my main logic I am using if with multiple conditions

```
if (Validate.checkPhrase(str,CONSTANT_ONE) 
|| Validate.checkPhrase(str,CONSTANT_TWO)|| /* multiple checks */ ){
//do something
}
```

Every time a new constant is added, I have to manually add it to the `if condition` as well.
Is there a way I can fetch all string,value pair from `Constant.java`  and use that in my logic.

Comment: Use enum, use a loop and iterate over its values, call checkPhrase and return true and break on successful validation, else keep on validating. if none of the iterations validates successfully return false.

Comment: If you find yourself constantly adding constants (get it?) you probably don't want to have them in a class (which means recompiling, redeploying, etc), but rather in a config file. This way you can easily modify the list of constants and only have to reload your application.

Comment: Also, based on your version of Java, you could use `switch` on Strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get all Constants you can use following code -

```
    HashMap<String,String> pairs= new HashMap<String,String>();
    Constants constants= new Constants();
    Field[] f = constants.getClass().getFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
        pairs.put(f[i].getName().toLowerCase(),f[i].get(constants).toString());
    }
    System.out.println(pairs);
```

**Update** -

Also as all fields are static we can access it using class name -

```
    HashMap<String,String> pairs= new HashMap<String,String>();
    for(Field field :Constants.class.getFields())
    { 
        pairs.put(field.getName().toLowerCase(),field.get(null).toString());
    }
    System.out.println(pairs);
```

Output of map -

```
{constant_two=VALUE_CONSTANT_TWO, constant_one=VALUE_CONSTANT_ONE}
```

Comment: In Fact there is no need to create the instance of class Constants if all the fields are static. Following should also work.        for(Field field :Constants.class.getFields()){
            System.out.println(field.getName()+ "   "+ field.get(null));
        }

Comment: What I wanted to say was the following code should work:      HashMap<String,String> pairs= new HashMap<String,String>();
    for(Field field :Constants.class.getFields())
    {
        pairs.put(field.getName().toLowerCase(),field.get(null).toString());
    }
    System.out.println(pairs);

Answer (score 2):

As you recognized if else-if blocks should usually be avoided as they make for difficult to read code and add unwanted dependency's.

in this case, why not put all your constants in a list or some other sort of container? then you can loop over the list using

`Validate.CheckPhrase(str, list[index])`

Answer (score 1):

you can try something similar to below:

```
enum CONSTANTS {
    VALUE_CONSTANT_ONE, VALUE_CONSTANT_TWO
}
```

then use it like:

```
        boolean result = false;
       //simulates your if ( checkPhrase ||checkPhrase)
        for (CONSTANTS c : CONSTANTS.values()) {
            result = Validate.checkPhrase(str,c.toString());
            if (result) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (result) {
            System.out.println("do your stuff");
        }
```

this way if you add a new enum the check will still remain unaffected.

If you dont want to compile again, use a property file , like this `constants.properties`

```
CONSTANT_ONE=VALUE_CONSTANT_ONE
CONSTANT_TWO=VALUE_CONSTANT_TWO
```

and can use it like below:

```
    Properties constants = new Properties();
    try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(
            "D:\\constants.properties");) {
        constants.load(fin);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // to check whats loaded
    System.out.println(constants);
    String str = "Your String";
    boolean result = false;
    for (String key : constants.stringPropertyNames()) {
        result = Validate.checkPhrase(str, constants.getProperty(key));
        if (result) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (result) {
        System.out.println("do your stuff");
    }
```

Comment: Here I will have to update `enum` every time I update `Constant.java` file ? Correct me if I am wrong , I have not worked with `enum` before

Comment: yes if you want a new constant, you need to put that in your enum and build your code again. Putting constants in a property/config file is better option if there are frequent changes, as compilation will not be required then. to know enum ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: also consider `Properties` class, you can load key value pairs from a file into it, then you can iterate over the values and perform desired checks. ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a better way to do this.

I suggest that you start looking for alternatives to your `Constants` class.

The most obvious one would be to replace the class with with a `enum` type.  That would allow you to do things like:

- iterating over all the values of the enum,
- `switch`-ing on an enum value, or
- defining predicates to subclassify the enum values.

Another approach is the put all of the constant strings into an array ... or a Set if some kind ... and either iterate over the array or use `contains` on the collection.  (Note that iterating over a large array of Strings is not efficient ...)

If you need the set of constant strings to be dynamic, then you could get rid of the *named* constants and the statically initialized array / collection.  Replace them with a `Map<String, Int>` and populate it from a configuration file or a database or something like that.  (This won't allow you refer to the constants in your source code using Java identifiers ... )

---

Note that `enum` types have been supported in Java for a number of years.  I'd have thought that your `Constants` class *should* have been replaced long ago ...

Comment: he would have to add a new switch case on introducing a new enum value.

Comment: @Shail016 - That is true.  But he's going to have to modify the code that uses the constants ... whatever.